# search a string in all the .log files in a directory and move the names of those files to .txt file using bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

I want to search a string in all the .log files in a directory and move the name of the file of the todays date(generic) which contains the specific string excluding the .log extension to a new .txt file and adding all the file names line by line(new line) in .txt file.

I tried this.

find /path/ -name '*.log' -exec bash -c '
filename=$(grep -lw "scp error" "$1")
echo "${filename%.log}" >> redrop_files.txt
' bash {} ;

Comment: Hey @freddt partially yes

Comment: actually I'm new to this scripting stuff so I'm not able to figure out to how to group the .log file with specific string and today's timestamp